# General database normalization

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Suppose that I have a table of products that I sell to my customers.

Each record has a productID and productName.

I can sell more than 1 product to each customer, but I want to allow customers to only order certain products.

What would those tables look like?

This is what I have so far:

```
PRODUCTS
+------------+-------------+
| PROD_ID    |  PROD_NAME  |
+------------+-------------+

CUSTOMER
+------------+-------------+
| CUST_ID    |  CUST_NAME  |
+------------+-------------+

ORDERS
+------------+-------------+
| ORDER_ID   |  CUST_ID    |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: When you say you want customers to only be able to order certain products, how will that restriction be enforced?

Comment: you need a junction table customer_product to define the products that customer can order.

Comment: How about `CUST_ID` in `ORDERS` and then add a new table named `CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` with `CUST_ID` and `PROD_ID` for the allowable products for the customers.

Comment: ORDERS should have `CUST_ID` as a foreign key

Comment: `ORDERS` should not have `PROD_ID` in it at all, but rather `CUST_ID`. Then you'll need a table `ORDER_PRODUCTS` with `ORDER_ID` and `PROD_ID` as foreign keys - this way an order can be made up of 1 or more products.

Comment: So should I go with creating CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS or ORDER_PRODUCTS to enforce allowable products for customers?

Comment: ORDER_PRODUCTS is the best option. A costumer has a order that has products. So Costumer -> order -> products: tables: costumer (id name) order (id, clientid, date...) products (id, description) order_products (order_id, product_id, qty, unit_price....)

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Your ORDER_PRODUCTS looks like the equivalent for the common Order_Line (with suggestion for probably redundant unit_price). OP will most likely need it - but shouldn't use it to store the restrictions, which product to sell to which customer, for which something focussing on Customer_Product (oops) seems in order (oops again).

Comment: @Angelina: How do you want to go without an ORDERS table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote and tested this with PostgreSQL, but the principles are the same for any SQL dbms.

Tables for products and customers are straightforward.

```
create table products (
  prod_id integer primary key,
  prod_name varchar(35) not null
);
insert into products values 
(1, 'Product one'), (2, 'Product two'), (3, 'Product three');

create table customers (
  cust_id integer primary key,
  cust_name varchar(35) not null
);
insert into customers values 
(100, 'Customer 100'), (200, 'Customer 200'), (300, 'Customer 300');
```

The table "permitted_products" controls which products each customer can order.

```
create table permitted_products (
  cust_id integer not null references customers (cust_id),
  prod_id integer not null references products (prod_id),
  primary key (cust_id, prod_id)
);
insert into permitted_products values 
-- Cust 100 permitted to buy all three products
(100, 1), (100, 2), (100, 3),
-- Cust 200 permitted to buy only product 2.
(200, 2);
```

Customer 300 has no permitted products.

```
create table orders (
  ord_id integer primary key,
  cust_id integer not null references customers (cust_id)
);
insert into orders values
(1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 100);
```

The table "order_line_items" is where the "magic" happens. The foreign key constraint on {cust_id, prod_id} prevents ordering products without permissions.

```
create table order_line_items (
  ord_id integer not null,
  line_item integer not null check (line_item > 0),
  cust_id integer not null,
  prod_id integer not null,
  foreign key (ord_id) references orders (ord_id),
  foreign key (cust_id, prod_id) references permitted_products (cust_id, prod_id),
  primary key (ord_id, line_item)
);

insert into order_line_items values
(1, 1, 100, 1), (1, 2, 100, 2), (1, 3, 100, 3);
insert into order_line_items values
(2, 1, 200, 2);
insert into order_line_items values
(3, 1, 100, 3);
```

You can start an order for customer 300 . . .

```
insert into orders values (4, 300);
```

. . . but you can't insert any line items.

```
insert into order_line_items values (4, 1, 300, 1);
```

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "order_line_items" violates foreign key constraint "order_line_items_cust_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (cust_id, prod_id)=(300, 1) is not present in table "permitted_products".
```